# How to change text color of TextFormField according to theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to change inputted text color as per the current theme, as text color is not a part of `InputDecorationTheme`.

[image]

As of now the only possible way to change inputted text color is to give style to `TextFormField` but that also not work when theme gets changed + in that way I need to repeat the similar code for each of my text field available in the app.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do by using property **subhead** inside the TextTheme

```
 theme: ThemeData( 
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.orange,
    accentColor: Colors.green,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ),
```

Or by using this :

```
 theme: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      primaryColor: Colors.orange,
      accentColor: Colors.green,
      textTheme: Theme.of(context)
          .textTheme
          .apply(bodyColor: Colors.red)`enter code here`

  ),
```

A blog on Text Styling in Flutter [https://medium.com/flutter- 
 community/beginners-guide-to-text-styling-in-flutter-3939085d6607](https://medium.com/flutter-%20%20%20community/beginners-guide-to-text-styling-in-flutter-3939085d6607)

**NOTE:** The Material Design typography scheme was significantly changed in the
current (2018) version of the specification
more info https://material.io/design/typography.

> The 2018 spec has thirteen text styles:

```
 NAME         SIZE  WEIGHT  SPACING
 headline1    96.0  light   -1.5
 headline2    60.0  light   -0.5
 headline3    48.0  regular  0.0
 headline4    34.0  regular  0.25
 headline5    24.0  regular  0.0
 headline6    20.0  medium   0.15
 subtitle1    16.0  regular  0.15
 subtitle2    14.0  medium   0.1
 body1        16.0  regular  0.5   (bodyText1)
 body2        14.0  regular  0.25  (bodyText2)
 button       14.0  medium   1.25
 caption      12.0  regular  0.4
 overline     10.0  regular  1.5
```

where "light" is `FontWeight.w300`, "regular" is `FontWeight.w400` and
"medium" is `FontWeight.w500`.

The [TextTheme] API was originally based on the original material (2014)
design spec, which used different text style names. For backwards
compatibility's sake, this API continues to expose the old names. The table
below should help with understanding the mapping of the API's old names and
the new names (those in terms of the 2018 material specification).

> Each of the [TextTheme] text styles corresponds to one of the
>   styles from 2018 spec. By default, the font sizes, font weights
>   and letter spacings have not changed from their original,
>   2014, values.

```
 NAME       SIZE   WEIGHT   SPACING  2018 NAME
 display4   112.0  thin     0.0      headline1
 display3   56.0   normal   0.0      headline2
 display2   45.0   normal   0.0      headline3
 display1   34.0   normal   0.0      headline4
 headline   24.0   normal   0.0      headline5
 title      20.0   medium   0.0      headline6
 subhead    16.0   normal   0.0      subtitle1
 body2      14.0   medium   0.0      body1 (bodyText1)
 body1      14.0   normal   0.0      body2 (bodyText2)
 caption    12.0   normal   0.0      caption
 button     14.0   medium   0.0      button
 subtitle   14.0   medium   0.0      subtitle2
 overline   10.0   normal   0.0      overline
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do by setting ThemeData as below .

```
 MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  )
 ...
```

Comment: I am using flutter 3.14 version, now there is no `subtitle1` attribute.

Comment: subtitle1 is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking in the `InputDecorationTheme` instead of the `TextTheme`.

The color property you are looking for should be `textTheme.body1.color` as in:

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.color
```

If not this one, it should be another of the `textTheme` properties.

Comment: In this way I need to add this for all textInputFields individually, i want to do this centrally from one point, so that if in future if there is any change i can do it from one location no need to go for all field and do the change.

Answer (score 0):

Using ThemeData (only for Material 3)

```
 MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  )
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a single ThemeData class for your application and you are setting all your theme properties there and you are **unable to locate textTheme property in your InputDecorationTheme**

**Solution:**

textTheme property is removed from InputDecorationTheme
you need to add textTheme seperately into your ThemeData constructor and then titleMedium property will set colour for TextField input colour.

> I have attached My ThemeData class. please have a look for more
> explanation

[image: Custom ThemeData class]

**Now how will you set this ThemeData class as your theme?**

> set theme in Material App

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: themeData(context),
  navigatorKey: locator<NavigatorService>().navigatorKey,
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  onGenerateRoute: router.Router.generateRoute,
  initialRoute: splashViewRoute,
);
```